# How would I pass data using a closure?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, closures, segue

Im trying to pass data from the cells in my HomeViewController to my CartViewController using the closure (addActionHandler) in my HomeCell.

Which I had working previously had working with passing data using `Tray.currentCart.cartItems.append(item)` in the cellForRowAt of the HomeVC.

But since I modified my ***Tray*** class by removing the `static let currentCart = Tray()`, I can't seem to get the cells in the HomeVC to pass data to the CartVC.

How would I be able to modify the code to make it work again to pass data from the HomeVc to the CartVC after the ATCBtn is pressed in the Home Cell

Im pretty close to my solution I just dont where to go from here to make it work... any help would be much much appreciated

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cartBtn: UIBarButtonItem! //segues data to CartVC

    var tray: [Tray] = []
    var itemSetup: [Items] = []
    var selectedItem: Items?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? CartViewController {
            vc.items = self.selectedItem
        }
    }
}
extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemSetup.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell") as? TestCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        let item = itemSetup[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(withItems: item)
        cell.addActionHandler = { (option: Int) in
           print("Option selected = \(option)")
        // Tray.currentCart.cartItems.append(item) //old code that passed data for selected cell in HomeVC to cartVC
           item.selectedOption = option
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController {

    var items: Items!
    var tray: [Tray] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        cartTableView.dataSource = self
        cartTableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartCell
     // let cart = Tray.currentCart.cartItems[indexPath.row] // code that was used to populate data in CartCells switched with new code below  
        let cart = tray[indexPath.row].cartItems[indexPath.section]
        cell.configure(withItems: cart)

        return cell
   }

}
```

---

```
class Tray {
    var cartItems = [Items]()
    var cart: Items!
    var brandName: String!
    // static let currentCart = Tray() code that has been removed
}
```

Comment: "On click on atcBtn, open the cartViewController with selected items?". Is this the requirement?

Comment: the atcBtn doesn't open the CartVC just passes the data selected item to populate the CartVC cells, the CartBtn in the NavBar of the HomeVC opens the CartVC

Comment: tray: [Tray] = [] in CartViewController should be populated from HomeViewController right?

Comment: yes it is used to populate the cells in the CartVC from the HomeVC.  ```var itemSetup: [Items] = []``` populates the cells of the HomeVC. The **Items** class draws data from cloudFirestore. I just didn't place the Firestore code in the HomeVC here on the question

Comment: numberOfSections is always 1?. If it is, then "tray[indexPath.row].cartItems[indexPath.section]"  can be avoided. Create a tray[] in HomeVC and pass to CartVC. Class Tray having items and items[] should be avoided unless needed.

Comment: Yes, the numberOfSections in the HomeVC and CartVC is 1. How would I be able do to the rest of your statement, I'm kind of confused on where to start

Comment: Try the solution below, if it is not working out, let me know :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202940/discussion-between-dili-and-evelyn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set class Tray like below

```
class Tray {
    var cart: Items
    var brandName: String
    init(cart: Items,
         brandName: String) {
        self.cart = cart
        self.brandName = brandName
    }
}
```

In HomeViewController, under addActionHandler append selected items to cart

```
cell.addActionHandler = { (option: Int) in
    print("Option selected = \(option)")
    item.selectedOption = option
    tray.append(Tray(cart: item, brandName: "<Brand Name>"))
}
```

Pass tray[] to CartViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? CartViewController {
        vc.items = self.selectedItem
        vc.tray = self.tray
    }
}
```

In CartViewController, pass items to cartCell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartCell
     let cart = tray[indexPath.row]
     cell.configure(withItems: cart.cart)
     return cell
}
```

Comment: the only issue im getting is in the CartVC cellForRowAt  ```cell.configure(withItems: cart)``` with the error code saying ***Cannot convert value of type 'Tray' to expected argument type 'Items'***

Comment: oh wait! I got it work!!:) in the HomeVC in the cellForRowAt I did ***self.*** tray.append(Tray(cart: item, brandName: "<Brand Name>")) in the CartVC cellForRowAt I did this cell.configure(withItems: cart ***.cart*** ) is it fine if I do it way? or will it cause me problems later on as I continue to code since im going to transition this to break it into sections when data is passed in the cells

Comment: cell.configure(withItems: cart .cart). This is correct, the solution is updated. It won't create an issue. If you need to add more sections, change the Class tray accordingly. I'm happy solution worked out for you :)

Comment: perfect thank you so much @Dili oh okay I didnt know I would have to modify the tray class to add sections to the CartVC.

Comment: you wouldn't mind giving me an sample to set me on the right path for how I would modify the Tray class?

Comment: if there are more sections. Create a section model like struct SectionModel {
    var title: String
    var rowItems: [Tray]
}. And use [SectionModel] as dataArray for tableview